# How to Convert LuminanceSource to Bitmap in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing, aforge

I want to do image processing with portable.aforge on instant frames that I get from the camera with Xamarin.Forms.

I took the example of zixng project.

In the Zxing project, instant frames from the camera are sent to the xamarin.Form core project as LuminanceSource.

LuminanceSource is https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Source/lib/LuminanceSource.cs

I need to convert this LuminanceSource source to System.Drawing.Bitmap

When i try to convert like the following code the bitmap is being null.

What I'm doing wrong about this and how can I do this properly?

```cs
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(luminanceSource.Matrix))
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    bitmap = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
    bitmap = bitmap.Clone(PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if luminanceSource.Matrix is null?

Comment: The LuminanceSource.Matrix element is not null. Always contains a byte array of frames from xamarin.android or xamarin.ios camera.